# Setup IIS in localhost as web development server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

How can I setup IIS 5.1 in Visual Studio 2008 as my web development server? I'm using Win XP, and I was using Cassini, but I want to give a tray to IIS instead of.

Comment: IIS 5? Wouldn't you need a Windows Server 2000 box for that?

Comment: maybe he meant IIS 5.1 (Win XP)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Go into Control Panel -> add remove programs -> enable / disable windows features, find IIS and install it.
2. Go to Start -> Accessories -> Administrative tools -> IIS Manager
3. Right click websites, add a new website, point the home directory to the root of your site.
4. Open up localhost
5. ????
6. Profit!

You might have to attach Visual Studio to the ASP.NET worker process to debug.

Answer (score 8):

It's in the web project's property pages, under Web->Servers->"Use local IIS web server"

Comment: nice, didn't know about this one ;p

Answer (score 1):

To attach Visual Studio to the ASP.NET worker proccess to debug go to menu Tools\Attach to Proccess or press CTRL + ALT + P and select aspnet_wp.exe or w3wp.exe.

More information [here](http://www.learn2debug.com/articles/visual-studio-net/debugging-an-asp-net-web-application-with-visual-studio-net.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

To develop Website using Visual developer 2008 with IIS instead of "ASP.NET Development Server", In the new website window under "Location" click on "Browse" to see the different Server options including IIS Server. User can select the server as IIS server instead of "File System", then the "Location" option will be "HTTP" instead of "File System".

In Visual developer 2008 under Properties->Start Option->Server->"Use local IIS server" option is not shown, Even though IIS server was installed and configured successfully. the only options shown are "use default server" and " Use custom server with base URL".

So in Visual developer 2008 to run on IIS server(If IIS server is installed), Need do the following:

New Website -> Under Locations Click on "Browse" -> Click on "Local IIS" and then select the "IIS Virtual Directory"(IIS vitual Directory which is directory created by the user while configuring IIS server) -> Open

While Running/debugging, the server which you selected while creating the website, the same server will used to open the website, that is while creating the website if you selected "IIS Server" then the website will be opened though IIS server.

One more thing is, while installing Visual developer 2008 and IIS server, If you installed IIS server after installing Visual studio then you need to do the following before creating new website:

Run ->cmd press enter (then enter the following Command)-> C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\Version# aspnet_regiis -i  press Enter then you get message after 3 seconds "ASP.net was installed successfully".
(*Version# will be v2.0.50727 in most cases)

Before everthing make sure you have installed and configured IIS server. To know how to install and configure IIS server check the following Link:
http://chalaki.com/install-iis6-windows-xp-professional-sp3-setup-run-csharp-cgi/425/

Hope this helps.